# SUSTITUIR DIGITOS EN UNA CADENA, DENTRO DE UN ARCHIVO CON SED CON SHELL SCRIPT

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

Tengo un archivo dentro de un `servidor suse` en este archivo hay una cadena en especifico que quiero modificar con valores entregados por el usuario pero ya me atore y no logro hacerlo este es mi código al momento:

```
#echo Introduce el TC
read -p "Introduce el TC que reportan: " dol2
echo $dol2
sed -i "s?4008:$ /  1  USD :00:0002:22+000000+00${dol2}+0000000100?4008:$ /  1  USD :00:0002:22+000000+00${dol1}+0000000100?" S_REG023.DAT
read -p "Introduce el TC correcto: " dol1
echo $dol1
sed -i "s?4008:$ /  1  USD :00:0002:22+000000+00${dol2}+0000000100?4008:$ /  1  USD :00:0002:22+000000+00${dol1}+0000000100?" S_REG023.DAT
echo "Cambio Realizado!!"
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con este comando de `sed`:

```bash
sed "s@4008:$ /  1  USD :00:0002:22+000000+00${dol2}+0000000100@4008:$ /  1  USD :00:0002:22+000000+00${dol1}+0000000100@"
```

Por algún motivo, siento que el símbolo "?" es problemático. Tan sólo lo cambié por el arroba "@".

Entiendo que en tu archivo, estas buscando las cadenas que tengan un signo de tipo de cambio almacenado en "dol2", y lo quieres reemplazar por lo que tenga "dol1".

Yo intenté esto, y funcionó:

```bash
dol1="%%"
dol2="))"

echo "4008:$ /  1  USD :00:0002:22+000000+00${dol2}+0000000100" | sed "s@4008:$ /  1  USD :00:0002:22+000000+00${dol2}+0000000100@4008:$ /  1  USD :00:0002:22+000000+00${dol1}+0000000100@"
```

Obteniendo esto:

```
4008:$ /  1  USD :00:0002:22+000000+00%%+0000000100
```

Osea, el valor de "dol1" es el que prevalece.

Al parecer el problema de todo esto es la elección de signos problemáticos que pueden indicarle o a la regex, o a bash, que los traten de tal o cual manera diferente a la que pensabamos que tendría.

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias a todos pero ya logre resolverlo les comparto mi script por si le sirve a alguien.

Saludos.

```
    #!/bin/bash 

# Script para corrección del archivo del tipo de Cambio del Dólar en cajas
# Realizado por J. Enrique López R. 
# Version 1, liberada el 10 de Febrero 2024

clear
#Se realiza respaldo del archivo P_REGXXXX.DAT con fecha
cp S_REG023.DAT Pruebas_Shell/S_REG023.DAT.BKP.$(date +%F)

#Se valida el TC incorrecto dentro del archivo P_REGXXXX.DAT
cat S_REG023.DAT
sleep 4
#Se realiza corrección del TC en el archivo P_REGXXXX.DAT
clear 
#Se declaran variables
let usd 
let dol
#Se toman valores de usuario y se asignan a las respectivas variables
read -p "Introduce el TC a corregir: " usd
read -p "Introduce el TC correcto: " dol
# Se realiza la corrección del archivo P_REGXXXX.DAT y se termina con la validación visual de parte del operador del TC corregido
sed -i "s?4008:$ /  1  USD :00:0002:22+000000+000$usd+0000000100?4008:$ /  1  USD :00:0002:22+000000+000$dol+0000000100?" S_REG023.DAT | xargs cat S_REG023.DAT
#sleep 3
```